# Modify Embedded Javascript Using Javascript File (Google Analytics / Amazon Webstore)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I would like to modify the default Google Analytics code in my Amazon Webstore to include the cross-site code.

Is it possible to use a javascript file loaded before the default GA code to add tracking code methods?

How can I add the following code:

```
pageTracker._setDomainName(".bioworldusa.com");
pageTracker._setAllowHash(false);
```

after this line of code:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
```

If you're wondering, I can't just replace the code because I need the transaction data to be submitted to Google Analytics. It would be more complicated to try to extract the transaction data into the new GA code than to modify the original.

This is the full GA code listed on most pages (expect the order confirmation page):

```
try {
  var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
  pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
```

Comment: The browser's going to execute the JavaScript code in `<script>` tags before you can get your hands on it, no matter what.

Comment: Ok, can I embed a `<script>` before the GA code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the same issue and I know how to execute the GA code you want to execute, especially since you are working with the older version of the code. I am working on the same issue with an Amazon webstore -- if you are able to upload a js file, and it looks like you are able to do this in files, I would suggest using the init() function which is deprecated but it still works - here is an example where I am doing something similar. I am setting the contents of a custom variable and creating the tracking object -- but I'm not firing the page tracker until later in the code.

Using the code below, replace the Custom Variable setting code with the linker and set Domain code you need for cross domain tracking. Since the GA code added by amazon doesn't try to set the domain the linker functions should prevent a second cookie from being created, and use the cookie data passed in the URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var gaJsHost = (("https:" ==     document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js'     type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-xxxxxxx-x"); 
pageTracker._initData();
pageTracker._setCustomVar(1, "GWO", utmx('combination').toString(), 1);} 
catch(err) {}</script>
```